# Magic: The Gathering – projecting images

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, magic-the-gathering

You are in a *Magic: The Gathering* commander game. It is now your first main phase and you control these permanents:

- One [Miirym, Sentinel Wyrm](https://scryfall.com/card/clb/284/miirym-sentinel-wyrm): "Whenever another nontoken Dragon enters the battlefield under your control, create a token that’s a copy of it, except the token isn’t legendary if that Dragon is legendary."
- Exactly $n$ instances of the enchantment [Parallel Lives](https://scryfall.com/card/isd/199/parallel-lives)*: "If an effect would create one or more tokens under your control, it creates twice that many of those tokens instead". $n$ is positive

You then cast [Astral Dragon](https://scryfall.com/card/clb/664/astral-dragon), which is indeed a Dragon: "When Astral Dragon enters the battlefield, create two tokens that are copies of target noncreature permanent, except they’re 3/3 Dragon creatures in addition to their other types, and they have flying". Assume that

- in the ensuing resolution you only target permanents you control and that have names mentioned in this puzzle (Miirym, Sentinel Wyrm; Parallel Lives; Astral Dragon)
- there is no external interference (instants played by opponents, abilities of other permanents, etc.)
- you cast no other spells before you proceed to combat.

What is the *exact* maximum number of 3/3 Dragon creature tokens you can create during this first main phase?

<sub>*This is not the only card to have the stated doubling effect. The other two non-legendary ones are [Anointed Procession](https://scryfall.com/card/akh/2/anointed-procession) (which I own in real life) and [Doubling Season](https://scryfall.com/card/2xm/164/doubling-season).</sub>

---

> The exact answer is a **very large number** that requires defining auxiliary functions to write down compactly. It is however far less than $2\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow6$.

Comment: "non-legendary permanents **like** Parallel Lives", so it doesn't have to be Parallel Lives?

Comment: "you only target permanents you control and that have names mentioned in this puzzle", Parrallel Lives is the only legal target, so why not just say that it copies that

Comment: Just with `n = 1` seems to be very hard to calculate. Let alone a generalisation for higher n

Comment: @IvoBeckers changing to just PL is a good idea; edited.

Comment: Is there any way to make this a self-contained puzzle? In its current state it relies on a bunch of links to a third party website for essential information.

Comment: @fljx Done. Now remove your close vote.

Comment: @fljx I was tempted to do that (edit to include the rules in) also, but I noticed that all other MtG puzzles also only use links instead of putting the definition in the question itself, so I cancelled my proposed edit. I think it's a nature of MtG, since the ruleset is huge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer:

Let's first just see what happens if you have 1 Parallel Lives.
When Astral Dragon enters the battlefied you have 2 choices:

1. You let Miirym's ability resolve first
2. You let Astral Dragon's ability resolve first

Case 1:

Miirym's ability will put 2 Astral Dragon tokens on the battlefield. There are now 3 Astral Dragon ETB abilities on the stack. They resolve one by one.
The first one will create $2 \cdot 2 = 2^2$ Parallel Lives tokens.
The second one will then create $2 \cdot 2^{1 + 2^2} = 2^6$ Parallel Lives tokens.
The third one will then create $2 \cdot 2^{1 + 2^2 + 2^6} = 2^{70}$ Parallel  Lives tokens for a total of $2^2 + 2^6 + 2^{70}$ tokens.

Case 2:
Astral Dragon will create $2 \cdot 2 = 4$ Parallel Lives tokens.
Miirym will create $2^5 = 32$ Astral Dragon tokens, causing also that many triggers to go on the stack.
The first one will then create $2^6$ Parallel Lives tokens.
The second one will then create $2^{70}$ Parallel Lives tokens.
The third one will then create $2 \cdot 2^{1 + 2^2 + 2^6 + 2^{70}}$ Parallel Lives tokens.
As you can see, this will blow up extremely fast. I could easily go on like that, but it will be a huge expression in the end. I'm not sure if there's a compacter notation you can write to get the total.

And this is only for $n = 1$. Maybe there's a better way to write it and to give a generalized notation for it, but I'm not mathematically adept enough for that.

In any case, no matter the $n$, there will only be one choice to make, and that's the  choice I demonstrated, and case 2 will be clearly the better choice then.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I'm new to MtG. In case 1, wouldn't Miirym's ability generate 4 Astral Dragon tokens due to Parallel Lives?

Comment: @justhalf without Parralel Lives it would have just be 1 token. Parallel Lives doubles that to 2

Comment: Ah, I somehow swapped the definition between Astral (which creates two) and Miirym (which creates one). Sorry and thanks!

Comment: You can use recursive formulation to get the exact formula, btw.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive function that models this question is:
find f(32) given:

f(0) = 5

f(x) = f(x-1) + 2 ^ (f(x-1) + 1)

Explanation of the function:

f(0) = 5 because when the first AD comes into play it makes 2 PLs which is doubled to 4. 4 + 1 = 5.
We are looking for f(32) because 2^5 ADs are created by Miirym because we have 5 PLs in play.

f(x) = f(x-1) + 2 ^ (f(x-1) + 1) because the number of PLs after each AD enters = Number of existing PLs + number of new PLs (2 ^ (f(x-1) + 1)). The number of new PLs is (2 ^ (f(x-1) + 1)) because AD creates 2 which is doubled a number of times = existing PLs

I plugged this function into [Hypercalc](https://mrob.com/pub/perl/hypercalc.html) at the suggestion of [Gottfried Helms](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1714/gottfried-helms)

The answer is 30 PT (3.553934904655 × 10^20)

Which means a power tower of 10s, 30 high with (3.553934904655 × 10^20) on top ie: 10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^10^(3.553934904655 × 10^20)

Comment: So what is the actual answer to the question?

Comment: @Rand al'Thor the answer is extremely large. It is at least 2^^33 but that is as far as I have got.